# Mongo DB compass is installed but not able to launch or open app

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongodb-compass

Mongo DB community edition is installed successfully but MongoDBCompass is not auto launching..I could even see MongoDBCompass icon created in desktop and able to search in taskbar...but I am not able to launch or open app by clicking on it...it simply keeps loading for some sec and stops.

I tried uninstalling and installing Mongo DB multiple times but no luck.
I have selected Install Mongo DB as service and selected option Run service as network service users in installation steps as well.

Could anyone please help me? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[checked checked for compass install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsrcf.png)

[Mono DB 64bit successfully installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ3IG.png)

Comment: Did you start the Mongo database? Did you install Mongo DB as a service?

Comment: yes in installation steps its selected Install Mongo DB as service and selected option Run service as network service users.

Comment: Did you check the MongoDB log file?

Comment: there are multiple lines in log file ..is there anything in specific that I need to search in log file?